# Using server share containing '\u' in its path in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I've a python list in which I'm using multiple server shares.
One of the server share goes like this: `\\\USServer\folder\filename$`
I'm using it in this way:`\\\USServer\folder\filename$` in the list.
I'm getting below error:

```
“Unicode Error ”unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes....truncated \UXXXXXX escape.
```

Is there any simple way of getting past this.

Comment: have you tried passing it as a raw string - `r'\\USServer\folder\filename'` ?

Comment: Vaulstein :thanks, it works now

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, it's a Python 3 feature.